# express-flash not showing message until refresh

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have express-flash installed and working, but only after I refresh the page I was redirected to. My controllers are using flash like so

```
req.flash("info", "No changes were made.");
res.redirect("/admin/dashboard");
```

In the view, I am importing a partial that looks like this.

```
<% if(messages.info) { %>
    <div class="modal-content flashModal" id="message-info">
        <div class="header">
            <span id="closeBtn">&times;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <strong>
                <%= messages.info %>
            </strong>
        </div>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

Not exactly sure what is causing the message to appear only after I have refreshed. It looks like the redirect is happening before the flash message? The documentation seemed straight forward enough but doesn't cover an issue like this. Any help is appreciated.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-flash

Answer (score 0):

Try to use render instead of redirect. See if it works.

```
res.render('dashboard);
```